# Best way to limit a single method of a class to a shared model?

Tags: swift

I have a utility class that is neither a singleton nor does it make use of any static properties or methods. However, I'd like to add a method `cleanDisk()` that I do want all instances to funnel through. I see three options. Make the method static:

```
class SomeUtility {
    static func cleanDisk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Only access this particular method through a shared instance:

```
class SomeUtility {
    static let shared = SomeUtility()

    func cleanDisk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Serialize the method through a static queue:

```
class SomeUtility {
    static let q = DispatchQueue(label: "utility")

    func cleanDisk() {
        SomeUtility.q.async {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an approach that is better than the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the DispatchQueue version has to do with anything — if this needs to be done on a particular single queue you'll do that in any case, and I don't see what it gets you otherwise. So that leaves a choice between a static method and a shared instance with an instance method.

Of those two, I prefer the shared instance, just because it is easier to mock for testing purposes. Mocking statics is possible but it's kind of a pain.

Otherwise there is really nothing to choose between them. Either way you're using `static` to guarantee singleton behavior.

---

However, it now seems that the entire question may be based on a false premise. Your comments on this answer seems to suggest that your goal here is to ensure that the functionality of `cleanDisk` is absolutely unable to overlap itself — that only one `cleanDisk` can be running simultaneously.

If that's the case, then the way to ensure that is to *do nothing*. An ordinary method in an ordinary class will ensure that:

```
class SomeUtility {
    func cleanDisk() {
        //
    }
}
```

Why? Because under ordinary circumstances, no matter how many instances of SomeUtility there are, you will only ever call `cleanDisk` *on the main thread*. But the main thread is a serial queue. So you can be certain only one `cleanDisk` can run at a time.

Conversely, *neither* of the first two solutions you propose can *prevent* different `cleanDisk` invocations from running simultaneously if your code is so perverse as to call it on *another* thread. For example, let's take the shared instance:

```
SomeUtility.shared.cleanDisk()
```

That code can perfectly well be called on *two different threads*, and therefore the code in `cleanDisk` can run simultaneously, overlapping, on those threads. Having a shared instance does *nothing* to prevent that. Same for the static function.

So if *that* is the goal, then running the `cleanDisk` functionality always on the same serial queue, either the main queue or some other serial queue, is indeed the only way to ensure it.

Comment: By making the queue a static property, doesn't it ensure that every instance of the utility class that calls the method will be serialized through the same serial queue?

Comment: The queue in the example is a serial queue, or am I mistaken on how to create serial queues? If there are multiple instances of this class and they all call the method in question simultaneously, all of those requests would be funneled FIFO on the static serial queue (no concurrency). This is the same effect produced by the other two patterns (static and shared instance), where if there are multiple instances of the class and they all call the method simultaneously, those requests would be funneled FIFO just the same (no concurrency).

Comment: That edit explains it very well. And if we don't want to run the method in question on the main queue—if we don't want the task of cleaning the disk interrupting the UI—and we don't want the method to ever overlap itself, then what's the best tool in the box?

Comment: I think I was just completely misled by your title, "limit a single method to a shared model". It seems now that the question was _never_ about that. If you want to ensure that there is _no_ sharing — which seems to me to be the _opposite_ of a "shared model"! — then indeed your third approach is the way to do that.

Comment: I have enough trouble with the Swift language, let's not get into English. Let me just circle back real quick to something in your edit. You said that with a shared instance, the method can still be called on two different threads and run simultaneously. If this shared instance has a serial queue as an instance property and the method is serialized through that queue, then it could never run simultaneously, correct?